# Jenkinsfile directives in shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to replace the repeating `options` and `triggers` that I happen to have in my declarative pipeline with a global *shared library*?

```
   pipeline {
        agent any

        options {
            gitLabConnection('GitLab')
            gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'commitit')
        }
        triggers {
            gitlab(triggerOnPush: true, triggerOnMergeRequest: true, 
            branchFilterType: 'All')
            pollSCM('H/30 * * * *')
        }
}
```

to

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    gitLabConf {}
}
```

Comment: the functionality can be achieved by using the plugin : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin...u can try this..